# PR AUC curve with drop in precision

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluations, auc, precision-recall-curve

I have this PR AUC plot, with both PCA and autoencoder related curves having a huge drop of precision in the beginning and then increasing again, with PCA hitting 0 as you can see in the zoomed in image.

Is this correct? What could be the cause for it? I can't seem to find an explanation for this different behavior from other PR AUC curves.

(the dataset is heavily imbalanced, only having 0,22% of positive class instances, I suspect this has something to do with it)

[image: PR plot]

[image: Zoom]

(There is a similar discussion here [AUC-PR but there is no recall or precision](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/auc-pr-but-there-is-no-recall-or-precision/104709#104709?newreg=f8ffb20aff4547a08a773c0d4ea3d8db), but I couldn't understand the answer and I just created an account so I can't comment yet...)